# Error unable to find env running javadoc in java 8

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

We are in the process of migrating our application from java7 to java8. Trying to get a new build in the new environment, I'm running into this error trying to generate the javadocs:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:aggregate (install) on project cfbtexecserv-0-main: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation: Unable to find javadoc command: Cannot run program "env": error=2, No such file or directory

I'm running on MacOS, running maven 3.3.3, java version 1.8.0_60. The "env" command is in my path in /usr/bin.

echo $PATH yields

> /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/Applications/ride-6.1.0-mac64/OracleJDK/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/sbin

echo $JAVA_HOME yields

> /Applications/ride-6.1.0-mac64/OracleJDK/Contents/Home

Comment: I'm using a JDK bundled with our version of Eclipse - Eclipse with our own custom plugins. This download also brought in the JDK. It looks like there was some issue with the JDK.

Using the normal JDK downloaded from oracle got me past this problem. I'm not sure what the root cause of it is though.